# How to implement a NSDate to force users to wait for 'lives' to reload

Tags: ios, timer, in-app-purchase, nsdate, clock

I am currently writing a game that uses a life system, the user is given 5 lives and cannot play again for 20 minutes (unless they buy more credits) if they run out.

I am wondering how to implement a timer to do so that runs off NSDate, basically a background timer that knows how long it's been between events.

I'm aware that users can change dates, so if theres a less complicated way around that it would be useful, but anything works for me right now. Thanks!

Comment: you need to accont for the fact that a user will log off or close the game while waiting, lets say, so for this issue, you would store the original time stamp startign time on the server. then invoke a method that takes as input this starting time on the server, and then checks for 20 mins based on the current time in the app. This is how I would do this. You can account for this using strict time zone recording when the user logs in or creates an account for the first time, so you based this algorithm on the fist timezone they ever used to sign up, then you run calculations on this time zone

Comment: If the user changes time zones, it won't matter, you always pull in the info for the user's original time zone on push time stampts based on that alone, or just make sure all user info is in GMT that will work as well. Each time the app is open, the time starts again, with the new input parameters from the server. or you can time stamp it in nsuserdefaults as well.

Comment: So, you take as input the difference between the time stamp on the sever vs current time, and then if this value is over 20 mins, then the user can play again, if thsi value is less than 20 mins, start a timer from the point of "how much time is left " in order to play for free. This will be the easiest way to calcualte time between app usages if the user closes the app and restarts. Otherwise, if you want to get fancy, use streaming, but this can get messy very quickly.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are approaching the task from the wrong direction.

When the user loses a game, you should save the date when the user will be allowed to play again. And because your user might quit your app, you have to persist that date somewhere (e.g. NSUserDefaults).

You then start a timer that fires like every second to show the user a countdown if he can't play. So you compare the saved date to now (i.e. `NSDate()`). If "now" is later or at the same time like the "next game date" the user is allowed to play again. If it's not, you update the countdown label.

When the user launches the app, you also have to check if the user is allowed to play. For this you have to get the persisted date and compare it like before.

Something like this will work:

```
import UIKit

// NSDate extension so you can use ==, <= and so on
public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs === rhs || lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedSame
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

extension NSDate: Comparable { }
// NSDate extension end



class YourGame: NSObject {
    var nextGameDate: NSDate?
    var nextGameTimer: NSTimer?

    func userDidLoseGame() {
        // update UI so user cannot play new game ...

        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        nextGameDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Minute, value: 20, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])!

        // save date
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(nextGameDate!, forKey: "nextGameDate")

        nextGameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("refreshNextGameTime:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        refreshNextGameTime(nextGameTimer!)
    }

    func refreshNextGameTime(timer: NSTimer) {
        if let nextGameDate = nextGameDate where nextGameDate >= NSDate() {
            let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
            formatter.unitsStyle = .Full
            formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Second]
            let timeUntilNextGameString = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate(), toDate: nextGameDate)
            print("Can't play. Next game in \(timeUntilNextGameString)")
            // show user time when he can play again ...
        }
        else {
            timer.invalidate()
            nextGameTimer = nil
            print("Can play")

            // update UI so user can play game ...
        }
    }

    func userDidStartApp() {
        // check if user is allowed to play game
        if let savedNextGameDate = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nextGameDate") as? NSDate where savedNextGameDate >= NSDate() {
            // update UI so user cannot play new game ...

            nextGameDate = savedNextGameDate
            nextGameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("refreshNextGameTime:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            refreshNextGameTime(nextGameTimer!)
        }
        else {
            // update UI so user can play game ...
        }
    }
}
```

It's a bit code and it might contain new concept like NSCalendar, but it should be pretty straight forward. Look up the documentation if you are not familiar with something.